# how to remove special character from the beginning and end of a string in c

Tags: c

Lets say I have a string like $$$hello$$$ how can I remove $$$ from the beginning and the end to make it look like hello.

another example is $$he$$o$$ after would be he$$o

Comment: It is not possible to actually "remove" a string from another string, as memory can't be moved. It can only be copied. In order to copy a substring from another string and write it into a new memory buffer, you can for example use the function [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) or [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy). Remember to add a null terminating character afterwards, if necessary. Both of these functions require you to know where the substring should start and where it should end.

Comment: To find the start of the substring to copy, you could do the following: `char string[] = "$$$hello$$$"; char *p = string; while ( *p == '$' ) p++;` After that, p will point to the start of the substring. An alternative would be to use the function [`strspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strspn)

Comment: Finding the end of the substring is harder. The null terminator of the entire string is located at `&string[strlen(string)]`. Therefore, you could write `p = &string[strlen(string)]; while ( p != string && *(p-1) == '$' ) p--;` Afterwards, it should point to the first character after the substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my alternate solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main( void )
{
    char source_string[] = "$$he$$o$$";
    char *p1, *p2;

    // find start of substring to extract
    p1 = source_string;
    while ( *p1 == '$' ) p1++;

    //find start of "trash" at end
    p2 = &source_string[ strlen(source_string) ];
    while ( p2 != p1 && *(p2-1) == '$' ) p2--;

    //calculate length of substring to extract
    size_t len = p2 - p1;

    //allocate space for dest_string including null terminating character
    char *dest_string = malloc( len + 1 );
    assert( dest_string != NULL );

    //extract substring
    memcpy( dest_string, p1, len );

    //add null terminating character
    dest_string[len] = '\0';

    //print the result
    puts( dest_string );

    //free the allocated buffer
    free( dest_string );
}
```

The solution above copies the substring to another buffer. If you want to copy the substring to the start of the source string instead, you can use the function [`memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove) instead of [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy). It is necessary to use this function instead, because `memcpy` does not allow the source and destination buffers to overlap, whereas `memmove` does.

Using this technique to copy the substring to the start of the source string, I propose the following solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main( void )
{
    char str[] = "$$he$$o$$";
    char *p1, *p2;

    // find start of substring to extract
    p1 = str;
    while ( *p1 == '$' ) p1++;

    //find start of "trash" at end
    p2 = &str[ strlen(str) ];
    while ( p2 != p1 && *(p2-1) == '$' ) p2--;

    //calculate length of substring to extract
    size_t len = p2 - p1;

    //copy substring to start of string
    memmove( str, p1, len );

    //add null terminating character
    str[len] = '\0';

    //print the result
    puts( str );
}
```

Comment: @Leo: I have now added a solution which does not copy to a new buffer, but rather overwrites the existing buffer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remember first occurance of a letter, this is `beg` pointer
2. Place `end` pointer after every letter
3. Print result from `beg` to `end`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char input_str[] = "$$$h&e$$l&&lo$$$";
  char* beg = NULL, *end = NULL;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(input_str); ++i) {
    if (input_str[i] >= 'a' && input_str[i] <= 'z') {
      end = &input_str[i+1];
      if (beg == NULL)
        beg = &input_str[i];
    }
  }
  if (!beg || !end)
    return 0;
  *end = 0;
  printf("%s\n", beg);
}
```

Comment: I think it was the intention of the OP to remove all consecutive `'$'` at the start and all consecutive `'$'` at the end, irrespective of what else was in the middle. Therefore, it does not seem appropriate to check for alphabetical characters. However, you are right that the question is not clear in this respect.

Comment: Please note that the ISO C standard does not guarantee that the character set stores all alphabetical characters consecutively. Although this is the case for the 7-bit ASCII character set, it is not true for [`EBCDIC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC). Therefore, the line `if (input_str[i] >= 'a' && input_str[i] <= 'z')` will not work with EBCDIC. If you also want it to work with character sets other than ASCII, I suggest you use [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) instead.

Comment: Also, note that you are only checking for lower-case letters (`'a'` to `'z'`), not upper-case ones (`'A'` to `'Z'`). You might want to use [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) or [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) before performing the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You could also allocate memory by copying the contents of the old string you want into a new string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *trim_word(char *word, char *to_remove)
{
    int beg_pos = 0;
    int end_pos = strlen(word);
    // at the end of the while loop, beg_pos represents the first position
    // in the string that is not the char to remove
    while (beg_pos < end_pos && word[beg_pos] == to_remove[0])
        beg_pos++;
    // at the end of the while loop, end_pos is the last position in string
    // that is not the char to remove
    while (end_pos - 1 > 0 && word[end_pos - 1] == to_remove[0])
        end_pos--;
    char *new_word = NULL;
    // allocate end_pos - beg_pos + 1
    new_word = malloc(end_pos - beg_pos + 1);
    if (new_word == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error malloc.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // copy in new_word starting at word[beg_pos] for (end_pos - beg_pos) characters
    strncpy(new_word, &word[beg_pos], end_pos - beg_pos);
    new_word[end_pos - beg_pos] = '\0';
    return new_word;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str = "$$$he$$o$$$";
    char to_remove = '$';
    char *trimmed_word = NULL;
    trimmed_word = trim_word(str, &to_remove);
    printf("old word: %s\t trimmed word: %s\n", str, trimmed_word);
    // free allocated memory in trimmed_word function
    free(trimmed_word);
    return 0;
}
```